# itertools combination can only work for one copy

Tags: python

when I use `combinations` from `itertools`, I find that I can only use it once, and afterwards I must repeat the line of code for it to work again. For example,

```
from itertools import combinations
comb = combinations( range( 0 , 5 ) , 2 )
xyLabels = [ (f'PCA{x}', f'PCA{y}') for x , y in  comb ]

>[('PCA0', 'PCA1'), ('PCA0', 'PCA2'), ('PCA0', 'PCA3'), ('PCA0', 'PCA4'), ('PCA1', 'PCA2'), ('PCA1', 'PCA3'), ('PCA1', 'PCA4'), ('PCA2', 'PCA3'), ('PCA2', 'PCA4'), ('PCA3', 'PCA4')]
```

Whereas If I do the following:

```
comb = combinations( range( 0 , 5 ) , 2 )
xyLabels = [ (f'PCA{x}', f'PCA{y}') for x , y in  comb ]
yxLabels = [ (f'PCA{x}', f'PCA{y}') for x , y in  comb ]
print(yxLabels)
> []
```

Printing the secod argument will only produce an empty list. However, to solve this I have to do the following:

```
comb = combinations( range( 0 , 5 ) , 2 )
xyLabels = [ (f'PCA{x}', f'PCA{y}') for x , y in  comb ]
comb = combinations( range( 0 , 5 ) , 2 )
yxLabels = [ (f'PCA{x}', f'PCA{y}') for x , y in  comb ]
print(yxLabels)
```

What is the reason behind it and how can I get it to work with only one `comb`?

Comment: Iterating over `comb` the first time consumes all the data, and so it is empty after that.

Comment: @JohnGordon ah okay, how can I store the content inside another variable so that I won't have to re-use comb?

Comment: @JohnGordon It looks like the following holds for me: ```new_comb = copy.copy(comb)```

Comment: Calling `combinations` is cheap precisely because it doesn't do much of anything until you start iterating over it. `combinations(range(0, 5), 2)` is probably no more expensive than `copy.copy(comb)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `comb` as a list instead of a generator - like this:

```
comb = list(combinations( range( 0 , 5 ) , 2 ))
```

That will then give you the result you expect. it will however increase your memory utilisation because you evaluate `comb` fully, instead of having it wait in the wings to hand you values on demand. Whether the memory/convenience tradeoff is worth it is your call.

Comment: With these small numbers it makes no difference with regards to memory. Thanks for sharing!